# How to add prefix from row at the beginning few next lines in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex, perl

I would like to use a line as a prefix for a few more lines. For an example, please consider the situation where I have these lines:

```
hostname-junek-1
;ge-1/0/1
;ge-1/0/2
;ge-1/0/5
;ge-1/1/27
;ge-1/1/39
hostname-junek-2
;ge-1/0/5
;ge-2/0/27
;ge-2/0/39
hostname-junek-3
;ge-1/1/1
;ge-2/1/13
;ge-2/1/17
;ge-2/1/11
```

I would like to receive something like this:

```
hostname-junek-1;ge-1/0/1
hostname-junek-1;ge-1/0/2
hostname-junek-1;ge-1/0/5
hostname-junek-1;ge-1/1/27
hostname-junek-1;ge-1/1/39
hostname-junek-2;ge-1/0/5
hostname-junek-2;ge-2/0/27
hostname-junek-2;ge-2/0/39
hostname-junek-3;ge-1/1/1
hostname-junek-3;ge-2/1/13
hostname-junek-3;ge-2/1/17
hostname-junek-3;ge-2/1/11
```

How do I do this? Either using notepad++ or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this can't be done with Notepad++.

Here is a solution with a perl oneliner:

```
cat inputfile 
hostname-junek-1
;ge-1/0/1
;ge-1/0/2
;ge-1/0/5
;ge-1/1/27
;ge-1/1/39
hostname-junek-2
;ge-1/0/5
;ge-2/0/27
;ge-2/0/39
hostname-junek-3
;ge-1/1/1
;ge-2/1/13
;ge-2/1/17
;ge-2/1/11
```

---

```
perl -ane 'if(/^(hostname-junek-\d+)\R/) {$host=$1;next}print "$host$_"' inputfile > outputfile
```

---

```
cat outputfile
hostname-junek-1;ge-1/0/1
hostname-junek-1;ge-1/0/2
hostname-junek-1;ge-1/0/5
hostname-junek-1;ge-1/1/27
hostname-junek-1;ge-1/1/39
hostname-junek-2;ge-1/0/5
hostname-junek-2;ge-2/0/27
hostname-junek-2;ge-2/0/39
hostname-junek-3;ge-1/1/1
hostname-junek-3;ge-2/1/13
hostname-junek-3;ge-2/1/17
hostname-junek-3;ge-2/1/11
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
/                           # regex delimiter
  ^                         # beginning of line
    (hostname-junek-\d+)    # group 1, hostname...followed by 1 or more digits
    \R                      # any kind of linebreak
/                           # regex delimiter

if the regex matches the current line, {
    $host=$1;               # save the hostname
    next                    # skip to next line
}                           # endif
print "$host$_"             # print the content of $host followed by the current line
```